# How can I recover from a failed cloud server instalation?

Tags: wireless

I have run into a situation.
I recently tried in install Ubuntu Server for Cloud (Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit version) on an old desktop pc. I made the startup disk, and everything was going fine. Everything went well until I had to choose the method that the server would use to connect to the internet, Ethernet or wireless. I choose wireless and it then prompted me to enter the ESSID. I choose for it to scan for available networks, however, it still could not find my network. I knew it wasn't my wireless because I was able to access it on my laptop during the entire process.

I decided to cancel the installation because I did not have the wireless information on hand. I tried access my router through my laptop's web browser but it could not connect for some reason, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. So, frustrated, I cancelled the installation and exited everything and tried to get into the regular desktop. The BIOS would load normally. However, now it does not load Windows XP. Instead, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor in the to left corner.
I'll admit, I was foolish for attempting to do this without a windows xp recovery disk on hand.

Is there anyway to revert what I have done?
Also, is there anyway to access my router through a web browser? I have done this before in Windows. Yet, whenever I enter the gateway, it says "unable to connect".
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a possible router failure. Try connecting over Ethernet cable to the router using the gateway address as wireless access to the router configuration is often turned off for security. Try testdisk for data recovery

Comment: @ElderGeek how is this related to "system-installation"?